# How to send dynamic created table as email in php

Tags: php, email

I have to send this table as a part of an email. I am not sure how it will work. I tried but it is not sending the data as email just sending the syntax of forloop in email. I am getting the list of querystring from url and want to add those values in table and send email..

This is my querystring

> quote-next.php?Tables=Tables&Chairs (More than 4)=Chairs (More than
>   4)&Fridge=Fridge&Large TV=Large TV&Chairs (Less than 4)=Chairs (Less
>   than 4)&Beds=Beds

This is my code which I am using to create table

```
$arr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $pieces = explode("&", $arr);

     print_r(str_replace('%20', ' ', $pieces[1]));
     echo '<table>';
                    for($i = 0; $i<count($pieces); $i++)
                    { 
                     echo '<tr><td>'.str_replace('%20', ' ', $pieces[$i]).'</tr></td>'; 
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
```

Can anybody tell me how can I send it as an email?

Comment: look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) at example #4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't echo to send an HTML part as an email. Actually, you have to dynamically set a variable for your HTML and then pass it to your php mail() function.

```
<?php    
    $arr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $pieces = explode("&", $arr);

    $email_body = "<table>";

    for($i = 0; $i<count($pieces); $i++){ 

        $email_body .= "<tr>";
        $email_body .= "<td>Your Lable</td>";
        /*
            Or if you have Label in $pieces array.
            $email_body .= "<td>$pieces[$i]</td>";
        */
        $email_body .= "<td>".str_replace("%20", " ", $pieces[$i])."</td>";
        $email_body .= "</tr>";

    }

    $email_body .= "</table>";

    mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $email_body);

?>
```

Comment: thanks its work  but one more thing I have to do I am getting values in table like this
Tables=Tables
Now I just want value after = how can i achieve that?

Comment: @AzadChouhan why not use `$_GET` instead of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` loop through all `$_GET` variables

Comment: The querystring is generating dynamically thats why I am using $_Server

Comment: @AzadChouhan glad to know it works for you, I have updated the answer please check it out. And don't forget to mark as correct if you think it helped you :)

Comment: can u please tell me how can i convert this Chairs (More than 4)=Chairs (More than 4)   into Chairs (More than 4) ??? @hmd

Comment: @AzadChouhan as far as I can understand, you are getting same values in each loop as you have keys. So, if I'm right. Why don't you simply use only 1 `<td>` for the value instead of two. It will automatically display "Chairs (More than 4)", "Large TV" and so on in each row. But if you are still confuse, try to post another question. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Separate the concerns:

- instead of echo, start string building (test with regular display):
- initialize: $message = ''
- echo => $message .= '< table >'
- send the string $message as message (test string sending separately)

Comment: can u please explain it further?